# Optimize slow MySQL query with lots of joins

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, optimization

I'm not sure how to improve the performance of this query. It takes over 100 seconds. I've added indexes and experimented with sub-queries but nothing seems to improve performance.

The Query

```
SELECT
GiftVoucher.VoucherNumber,
GiftVoucher.DateIssued,
GiftVoucher.DateRedeemed,
R.old_name as RedeemedBy,
I.old_name as IssuedBy,
RH.Name as RedeemedForHotel,
V.old_name as VoidedBy,
GiftVoucher.VoidedReplacment,
GiftVoucher.VoidedDescription
FROM GiftVoucher
LEFT JOIN StaffToWp R ON GiftVoucher.RedeemedBy=R.old_id
LEFT JOIN StaffToWp I ON GiftVoucher.IssuedBy=I.old_id
LEFT JOIN StaffToWp V ON GiftVoucher.VoidedBy=V.old_id
LEFT JOIN Hotel RH ON GiftVoucher.RedeemedForHotelID=RH.HotelID
WHERE DateIssued > "2011-12-31 23:59:59"
LIMIT 0, 20000
```

GiftVoucher Structure

```
GiftVoucher

Column  Type    Null    Default Comments
GiftVoucherID   int(11) No       
ParentGiftVoucherID int(11) Yes     NULL     
Value   decimal(19,4)   No       
VoucherNumber   varchar(150)    Yes     NULL     
SendToRecipientAddress  int(11) No       
DateIssued  datetime    No       
DateRedeemed    datetime    Yes     NULL     
GiftVoucherPurchaseID   int(11) No       
RedeemedBy  int(11) Yes     NULL     
IssuedBy    int(11) Yes     NULL     
Active  int(11) No       
RedeemedForHotelID  int(11) Yes     NULL     
RedeemedTo  int(11) Yes     NULL     
Redeemed    int(1)  No  0    
RedeemedAmount  decimal(19,4)   Yes     NULL     
Voided  int(1)  No  0    
VoidedDate  datetime    Yes     NULL     
VoidedBy    int(11) Yes     NULL     
VoidedReplacment    int(11) Yes     NULL     
VoidedDescription   mediumtext  Yes     NULL     
SystemVersion   int(11) No       
Indexes

Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  GiftVoucherID   23191   A   No  
VoidedBy    BTREE   No  No  VoidedBy    2   A   Yes 
RedeemedBy  BTREE   No  No  RedeemedBy  244 A   Yes 
IssuedBy    BTREE   No  No  IssuedBy    212 A   Yes 
DateIssued  BTREE   No  No  DateIssued  23191   A   No  
RedeemedForHotelID  BTREE   No  No  RedeemedForHotelID  10  A   Yes
```

StaffToWP Structure

```
StaffToWp

Column  Type    Null    Default Comments
id  int(11) No       
old_id  int(11) No       
old_name    varchar(255)    No       
new_id  int(11) No       
new_name    varchar(255)    No       
Indexes

Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  id  121 A   No  
old_id  BTREE   No  No  old_id  121 A   No  


Space usage:
Data    4,524   B
Index   7,168   B
Total   11,692  B
    Row Statistics:
Format  dynamic
Rows    121
Row length ø    37
Row size ø  97 B
Next autoindex  122
Creation    Sep 16, 2015 at 12:01 PM
Last update Sep 16, 2015 at 12:01 PM
Last check  Sep 16, 2015 at 12:01 PM
```

Hotel Strcture

```
Hotel

Column  Type    Null    Default Comments
HotelID int(11) No       
Name    varchar(250)    No       
Telephone   varchar(50) No       
AccommodationUrl    varchar(250)    No  ''   
ColourClass varchar(50) Yes     NULL     
Indexes

Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  HotelID 7   A   No  
HotelID BTREE   No  No  HotelID 7   A   No
```

EXPLAIN results

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  GiftVoucher ALL DateIssued  NULL    NULL    NULL    22180   Using where
1   SIMPLE  R   ref old_id  old_id  4   milsomho_voucher.GiftVoucher.RedeemedBy 1   
1   SIMPLE  I   ref old_id  old_id  4   milsomho_voucher.GiftVoucher.IssuedBy   1   
1   SIMPLE  V   ref old_id  old_id  4   milsomho_voucher.GiftVoucher.VoidedBy   1   
1   SIMPLE  RH  eq_ref  PRIMARY,HotelID PRIMARY 4   milsomho_voucher.GiftVoucher.RedeemedForHotelID 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos for actually including the table structures and explain plan!

> DateIssued > "2011-12-31 23:59:59"

Presumably this filter would significantly reduce the number of rows returned by the query. But you'll see that the DBMS is not using the index on DateIssued:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  GiftVoucher ALL DateIssued  NULL    NULL    NULL    22180   Using where
```

The likely reason for this is the mismatch in types which is forcing MySQL to do a type conversion on each row in the source table.

Try:

```
DateIssued > 20111231235959
```

You also might consider other ways to be more specific about the data you are extracting (more filtering) and denormalizing the data to reduce the number of tables LEFT joined.

The cardinality figures look rather low - is this a test data set? Are they out of date?

Comment: That is all great advice thanks. I tried exporting the same result from phpMyAdmin and it came through quite quickly which leads me to believe that the issue isn't the size of the query but something do with querying via the web server. I have <?php set_time_limit(0); ?> but it still gives me an error 500 after about a minute. Sorry to go off-topic.

Comment: This query is not causing the `500`.

Comment: @Rick: What makes you think that? (although the webserver should return a 504 on a timeout in PHP, not all of them do)

Comment: OK, the query crashing, or the query causing PHP to mess up, could cause a 500.  However, having huge (or infinite) time limits in both PHP and MySQL cannot lead to a 500 or 504, can it?

Answer (score 0):

Even your query seems optimized further you can check as per below mentioned 2 approaches if can reduce time-

First Approach:

create combined index instead of individual index in GiftVoucher table, you have to check with different combinations like single combined index on redeemedby, issuedby, voidedby, RedeemedForHotelID, dateissues. If it not work then try with limited fields combination and use by which combination you can get better results.

Second Approach:

As you need first 20,000 rows then apply a date range (lower and upper range) by which you can get at least 20,000 rows surely and make it as sub-query then apply next left join with this sub-query. In this way mysql has to match limited records of very first left table (sub-query data) with other right tables.

Answer (score 0):

The table has about 22K rows?  Yet you are asking for 20K?  Sounds like the `LIMIT` is useless; why have it?

That date is 4 years ago...  Does it include most of the `GiftVoucher`?  If so, an index on `DateIssued` probably won't be used.  This is because it may be more efficient to scan the table rather than bouncing between the index and the data.

Composite index?  None would help.  Only one column, `DateIssued`, is referenced in `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, and `ORDER BY`.

Is `old_id` indexed in the other tables?  It seems to be ("ref"), but it does not seem to be the `PRIMARY KEY`.

You have a `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY`.  So you don't care which 20K rows you get?

You have not provided `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; I assume the Engine is InnoDB?

`DateIssued > "2011-12-31 23:59:59"` is fine for comparing a `DATETIME`; no need to use a different syntax.

Shrinking the table sizes would help a tiny bit...  You have lots of `INTs` (signed, 4-byte), where you could probably use `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2-bytes, range 0..65535).  Or `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED`.

One thing that might help a bit...  A "covering index":

```
INDEX(old_id, old_name)
```

on `StaffToWp`.  This would make it a bit more efficient to look up the `old_id` to get the `old_name`, which seems to be the purpose of 3 of the `LEFT JOINs`.